# I want make able to change dark/light mode with Switch at DrawerHeader

Tags: android, flutter, dart, switch-statement, android-dark-theme

**I want make able to change dark/light mode with Switch at DrawerHeader. But i'm getting an error.**

Error: Could not find the correct Provider above this Consumer Widget
This likely happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider
of your choice. There are a few common scenarios:

- The provider you are trying to read is in a different route.
  Providers are "scoped". So if you insert of provider inside a route, then
  other routes will not be able to access that provider.
- You used a `BuildContext` that is an ancestor of the provider you are trying to read.
  Make sure that Consumer is under your MultiProvider/Provider.
  This usually happen when you are creating a provider and trying to read it immediately.

**anasayfa.dart**

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<ThemeNotifier>(
      create: (_) => ThemeNotifier(),
      child: Consumer<ThemeNotifier>(
        builder: (context, ThemeNotifier notifier, child) {
          return MaterialApp(
            title: 'Flutter Theme Provider',
            theme: notifier.darkTheme ? dark : light,
            home: Anasayfa(),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Anasayfa extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AnasayfaState createState() => _AnasayfaState();
}

class _AnasayfaState extends State<Anasayfa> {
  int currentPage = 0;

  nested() {
    return NestedScrollView(
        headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
          return [
            SliverAppBar(
              toolbarHeight: 40,
              expandedHeight: 92.0,
              floating: false,
              pinned: true,
              flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                background: Image.asset(
                  "assets/images/besmele.jpg",
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              ),
              actions: [
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle),
                  color: Colors.white,
                  onPressed: () {},
                ),
              ],
            )
          ];
        },
        body: Container());
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: nested(),
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: DrawerDosyasi(),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: CurvedNavigationBar(
        color: Colors.blue,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        buttonBackgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        height: 50,
        items: <Widget>[
          Icon(
            Icons.campaign,
            size: 20,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          Icon(
            Icons.supervisor_account,
            size: 20,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          Icon(
            Icons.home,
            size: 20,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          Icon(
            Icons.video_collection_rounded,
            size: 20,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          Icon(
            Icons.menu_book_rounded,
            size: 20,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ],
        animationDuration: Duration(
          milliseconds: 300,
        ),
        index: 2,
        animationCurve: Curves.bounceInOut,
        onTap: (index) {
          debugPrint("Current index is $index");
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**drawerDosyasi.dart**

```
class DrawerDosyasi extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DrawerDosyasiState createState() => _DrawerDosyasiState();
}

class _DrawerDosyasiState extends State<DrawerDosyasi> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        children: <Widget>[
          DrawerHeader(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.blue,
            ),
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: Consumer<ThemeNotifier>(
                    builder: (context, notifier, child) => Switch(
                      onChanged: (val) {
                        notifier.toggleTheme();
                      },
                      value: notifier.darkTheme,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  flex: 3,
                  child: CircleAvatar(
                    radius: 60,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(flex: 1, child: SizedBox.expand()),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.home),
            title: Text('Anasayfa'),
            tileColor: Colors.white,
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.account_circle),
            title: Text('Profil'),
            tileColor: Colors.white,
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.campaign),
            title: Text('Duyurular'),
            tileColor: Colors.white,
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.account_box),
            title: Text('Hocalar'),
            tileColor: Colors.white,
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.library_books),
            title: Text('Dergiler'),
            tileColor: Colors.white,
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.video_collection_rounded),
            title: Text('Canlı Dersler'),
            tileColor: Colors.white,
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.menu_book_rounded),
            title: Text('Kütüphane'),
            tileColor: Colors.white,
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.supervisor_account),
            title: Text('Tartışmalar'),
            tileColor: Colors.white,
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.create),
            title: Text('Yazı Gönder'),
            tileColor: Colors.white,
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.message_rounded),
            title: Text('İletişim'),
            tileColor: Colors.white,
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.exit_to_app_rounded),
            title: Text('Çıkış'),
            tileColor: Colors.white,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**theme.dart**

```
ThemeData light = ThemeData(
    brightness: Brightness.light,
    primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
    accentColor: Colors.blue,
    scaffoldBackgroundColor: Color(0xfff1f1f1));

ThemeData dark = ThemeData(
  brightness: Brightness.dark,
  primarySwatch: Colors.indigo,
  accentColor: Colors.green[700],
);

class ThemeNotifier extends ChangeNotifier {
  final String key = "theme";
  SharedPreferences _prefs;
  bool _darkTheme;

  bool get darkTheme => _darkTheme;

  ThemeNotifier() {
    _darkTheme = true;
    _loadFromPrefs();
  }

  toggleTheme() {
    _darkTheme = !_darkTheme;
    _saveToPrefs();
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

**pubspec.yaml**

```
name: mto
description: A new Flutter application.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase_database: ^4.3.0
  page_transition: ^1.1.7+2
  simple_animations: ^2.2.3
  curved_navigation_bar: ^0.3.4
  provider: ^4.3.2+2
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.12+4

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter


# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/images/
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

**The application looks like this**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcpU3.png)

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced your above code with a few exceptions where I had to comment out some lines code. The code worked as expected. I was able to switch the theme from dark to light by tapping on the Switch. Please see the screen recording. Also checkout the code I reproduced below.

[image: Screen Recording]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:curved_navigation_bar/curved_navigation_bar.dart';

void main() => runApp(
      ChangeNotifierProvider<ThemeNotifier>(
        create: (_) => ThemeNotifier(),
        child: MyApp(),
      ),
    );

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final ThemeNotifier notifier = Provider.of<ThemeNotifier>(context);
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Theme Provider',
      theme: notifier.darkTheme ? dark : light,
      home: Anasayfa(),
    );
  }
}

class Anasayfa extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AnasayfaState createState() => _AnasayfaState();
}

class _AnasayfaState extends State<Anasayfa> {
  int currentPage = 0;

  nested() {
    return NestedScrollView(
        headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
          return [
            SliverAppBar(
              toolbarHeight: 40,
              expandedHeight: 92.0,
              floating: false,
              pinned: true,
              flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                  // background: Image.asset(
                  //   "assets/images/besmele.jpg",
                  //   fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  // ),
                  ),
              actions: [
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle),
                  color: Colors.white,
                  onPressed: () {},
                ),
              ],
            )
          ];
        },
        body: Container());
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: nested(),
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: DrawerDosyasi(),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: CurvedNavigationBar(
        color: Colors.blue,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        buttonBackgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        height: 50,
        items: <Widget>[
          Icon(
            Icons.campaign,
            size: 20,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          Icon(
            Icons.supervisor_account,
            size: 20,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          Icon(
            Icons.home,
            size: 20,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          Icon(
            Icons.video_collection_rounded,
            size: 20,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          Icon(
            Icons.menu_book_rounded,
            size: 20,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ],
        animationDuration: Duration(
          milliseconds: 300,
        ),
        index: 2,
        animationCurve: Curves.bounceInOut,
        onTap: (index) {
          debugPrint("Current index is $index");
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DrawerDosyasi extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DrawerDosyasiState createState() => _DrawerDosyasiState();
}

class _DrawerDosyasiState extends State<DrawerDosyasi> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        children: <Widget>[
          DrawerHeader(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.blue,
            ),
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: Consumer<ThemeNotifier>(
                    builder: (context, notifier, child) => Switch(
                      onChanged: (val) {
                        notifier.toggleTheme();
                      },
                      value: notifier.darkTheme,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  flex: 3,
                  child: CircleAvatar(
                    radius: 60,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(flex: 1, child: SizedBox.expand()),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.home),
            title: Text('Anasayfa'),
            tileColor: Colors.white,
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.account_circle),
            title: Text('Profil'),
            tileColor: Colors.white,
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.campaign),
            title: Text('Duyurular'),
            tileColor: Colors.white,
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.account_box),
            title: Text('Hocalar'),
            tileColor: Colors.white,
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.library_books),
            title: Text('Dergiler'),
            tileColor: Colors.white,
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.video_collection_rounded),
            title: Text('Canlı Dersler'),
            tileColor: Colors.white,
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.menu_book_rounded),
            title: Text('Kütüphane'),
            tileColor: Colors.white,
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.supervisor_account),
            title: Text('Tartışmalar'),
            tileColor: Colors.white,
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.create),
            title: Text('Yazı Gönder'),
            tileColor: Colors.white,
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.message_rounded),
            title: Text('İletişim'),
            tileColor: Colors.white,
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.exit_to_app_rounded),
            title: Text('Çıkış'),
            tileColor: Colors.white,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

ThemeData light = ThemeData(
    brightness: Brightness.light,
    primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
    accentColor: Colors.blue,
    scaffoldBackgroundColor: Color(0xfff1f1f1));

ThemeData dark = ThemeData(
  brightness: Brightness.dark,
  primarySwatch: Colors.indigo,
  accentColor: Colors.green[700],
);

class ThemeNotifier extends ChangeNotifier {
  final String key = "theme";
  SharedPreferences _prefs;
  bool _darkTheme;

  bool get darkTheme => _darkTheme;

  ThemeNotifier() {
    _darkTheme = true;
    //_loadFromPrefs();
  }

  toggleTheme() {
    _darkTheme = !_darkTheme;
    //_saveToPrefs();
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. I studied the codes carefully.

-First, I noticed that you used too much "const". Why? I want to learn.

-I tried to reproduced codes like you one by one. But got same error.

-I copied you codes with ctrl + c and pasted to mine. Got same error.

-Finally, I commented out all lines code at other pages, copied all of your codes and pasted to one page. But got same error.

Comment: There are no issues in your code. Have you correctly added provider: in the pubspec.yaml file. What version of provider are you using?

Const constructors help Flutter to rebuild only widgets that should be updated. Since const are compile-time constants they improve the performance of your app by letting Flutter know that this object will never change during the entire runtime of the code. I user dart lint https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/ that mark the code in IDE where I need to enter const.

Comment: I checked my pubspec.yaml file. Version of provider is "provider: ^4.3.2+2" so last version. If you want, I can add the pubspec.yaml  file to the main text above. Thanks for explaining the const.

Comment: Yes, please add your pubspec.yaml to your main question.

Comment: Okay, i added the pubspec.yaml file

Comment: Again I did not get any error messages despite me using your pubspec.yaml and copy pasting entire code. Please check my updated code above. I have made some minor changes, hopefully you do not get any errors now.

Comment: Got same error again. I uploaded the screenshot. The screen looks like this on me.

Comment: I will probably take this feature out of my app. I wasted too much time. Thank you for your help.